# Visual Editor - Colorize Shortcodes

Tags: wp-insert-post, wp-editor

I want to highlight shortcodes in the WordPress visual editor in a specific color. 
E.g. I Have the following Shortcodes

```
[shortcode1] Some text [/shortcode1]
              ...
[shortcode2] Some text [/shortcode2]
```

and want to give each of them a unique color, so the user could easily see what he should change.

I have found some solutions to syntax highlighting the HTML Editor but no one for the visual editor itself.

Comment: Please note, plugin recomendations are off topic, I have removed that part :-)

Comment: Did you consider [Shortcake UI](http://wptavern.com/shortcake-a-ui-for-wordpress-shortcodes)? (I'm not related to that project)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to get a working solution.

What you need:

TinyMCE Advanced plugin

What you should do:

Customize the Visual Blocks Plugin that comes with the TinyMCE plugin and add css classes for each element you would to highlight (just loop through all p elements and parse the innerHTML and check if it contains your specific pattern).

Finally it looks something like this:
[image]